# Jenkins Gerrit-trigger leaving comments

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

Ive setup a Jenkins pipeline and defined it to trigger based on a Gerrit event which works fine.
However, every time a build is triggered, it leaves a comment in the gerrit

```
Jenkins Build.svc Patch Set 1: Build Started
```

and based on its success and failure, it leaves +1 or -1

How do I stop it from leaving the comment and giving +1/-1 from this particular pipeline ?

I've looked at Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> Gerrit triggers but i dont see anything i can configure specific to this pipeline. it looks like they are global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Gerrit Trigger section open the Advanced settings and skip voting. That should work.

[image: Gerrit Trigger Skip Vote]